# Collapsing multiple Javascript events down to a single event

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I have a function that gets fired off every time the user types a key. I'd like to collapse these events down a bit, so that the events get fired with a maximum rate of (say) 500ms.

Is there an easy way to do this in Javascript or a popular library? Or should I write my own timeout logic?

Comment: Look for "debounce" or "throttle" in JavaScript.

Comment: what exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fairly easy to write your own :

```
$('element').on('keyup', function() {
    clearTimeout($(this).data('timer')); // stops the below function if new key
                                         // is pressed within 0.5 seconds
    $(this).data('timer', 
        setTimeout(function() {

            // do stuff

        }, 500)
    )
});
```

or you could use a plugin, [**jQuery Throttle**](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-throttle-debounce) seems to be popular.

Comment: It is, and I've written enough solutions of my own over the years that turn out to be built-ins...I just figured I'd ask.

Comment: Well, [$.throttle](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-throttle-debounce) seems to be popular if you like plugins !